# What does data16 mean in objdump output?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, objdump

Using the objdump command:

```
$ objdump -M att -d  wrapping_counters_test
```

I produced this listing (this is just a snippet from the entire listing):

```
100000ae5:   31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
100000ae7:   31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
100000ae9:   49 89 c4                mov    %rax,%r12
100000aec:   b8 00 ca 9a 3b          mov    $0x3b9aca00,%eax
100000af1:   66 66 66 66 66 66 2e    data16 data16 data16 data16 data16 nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
100000af8:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00
100000aff:   00
100000b00:   8d 75 01                lea    0x1(%rbp),%esi
```

What does the line of `data16`s following the 2nd `mov` instruction mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's just a multi-byte `nop` inserted for alignment padding. Notice how the last line is at address `100000b00` which is 16 byte aligned. `data16` itself is an operand size override prefix. Normally only one is used and it's not disassembled separately, but included in the instruction suffix. You can see you have six `66` instances but only five `data16` appear, the sixth is the `w` in the `nopw` and you normally only get that. Only the extra prefixes inserted to lengthen the instruction are shown separately.

Comment: We need to assign numbers to all the new "Jesters" in StackOverflow : Jester001, Jester002, ... (http://stackoverflow.com/users/4349838/jester).